# How can I secure this user cookie?

Tags: php, mysql, security, cookies, session-cookies

So I've a user login network and it creates a cookie upon login. I need to know how to secure it because at the moment I can edit the cookie and it will give me access to any username I update the loggedin cookie to. This is the existing code:

```
<?
$username = $_REQUEST['username'];
$goto = $_REQUEST['goto'];
$expdate = time() + 864000;

setcookie('loggedin',"$username",$expdate, "/");

echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV=Refresh CONTENT=\"0; URL='/$goto.html'\">";
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you! I'm fairly new to cookies and PHP in general.

Comment: cookies will always be editable - your security methods need addressing, use sessions instead

Comment: Why you don't use sessions?

Comment: If I use a public computer (e.g. at a library), i will be able to access the last persons account

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting: `?goto="><script>…</script>`.

Answer (score -1):

In PHP, setting the arguments for cookies is done through some optional arguments on the “setcookie” function:

```
setcookie( name, value, expire, path, domain, secure, httponly);

// Open
setcookie( 'UserName', 'Bob', 0, '/', '.example', false, false);

// Locked Down
setcookie( 'UserName', 'Bob', 0, '/forums', 'www.example.com', isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]), true);
```

Comment: This is not related to what the OP is asking.